# How to add an attribute to the dynamoDB table item if it does not exist and add value to that attribute?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to add value to the attribute "dataname" which is type LIST in the dynamoDB table.

```
        response = table.update_item(
            Key={"name": xyz},
            UpdateExpression="SET dataname = list_append(dataname, :i)"
            ExpressionAttributeValues={
                ':i': [1200, readonly],
            },
        )
```

The above logic works only if the attribute "dataname" is already present in the item.
If the attribute is not present it gives the following error: "The provided expression refers to an attribute that does not exist in the item".

Is there a way to add the attribute "dataname" if it does not exist in the item and then update the values ?
I'm using Python language for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently used an implementation like this:

```py
import boto3

update_expression = "SET #dataname = list_append(if_not_exists(#dataname, :empty_list), :i)"

dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
result_table = dynamodb.Table(TABLE_NAME)

result_table.update_item(
    Key={
        "name": "xyz",
    },
    UpdateExpression=update_expression,
    ExpressionAttributeNames={
        "#dataname": "dataname",
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ":empty_list": [],
        ":i": [1200, readonly],
)
```

This is adapted from an implementation for NodeJS I found on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56003323/6485881) by Nasreen Ustad) and translated to Python. ([Looks like there is a sort of canonical answer for this without the complete implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34951043/is-it-possible-to-combine-if-not-exists-and-list-append-in-update-item))

It basically works like this:

1. It checks if the `#dataname` attribute exists, if that's the case it is used, otherwise the value of `:empty_list` will be used in its place
2. Then the new value(s) will be appended to the list.

Comment: Thank you. This works exactly as i wanted. @Maurice

Comment: Out of curiosity, suppose the attribute "dataname" is a MAP, is it still possible to do this ?
Guess list_append won't work then. @Maurice

Comment: I'd be surprised if list_appends works for map, you're probably right about that. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.SET.AddingNestedMapAttributes) is an example of setting nested map attributes, you can probably use the `if_not_exists` technique there as well - just add an empty map and not an empty list ;-)